# select a row based on a condition that requires examining general values in other rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am implementing this in Python with SQLite 3.
I have the following table ‘parts’ with attributes part1, part2, and supplier.

```
part1 part2 supplier
a     j     Foo
b     g     Bar 
c     d     Nom
a     b     Bar
b     k     Bar
c     m     Bar
c     l     Foo
```

I want to select `part1` and `supplier` if `part1` is obtainable from more than one supplier (or not with one only supplier), independent of `part2`. 
The result I am looking for is:

```
a, Foo
a, Bar
c, Nom
c, Bar
c, Foo
```

or simply a,c.
I don’t want b because it only occurs with Bar.

I tried this:

```
co.execute("SELECT ar.part1,ar.supplier FROM parts ar, parts ts WHERE ar.part1 = ts.part1 AND ar.supplier != ts.supplier ")
for row in co.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

The results were pairs of `part1` and `supplier` but only included 2 suppliers, and the table has 20.

Answers using case imply stating specific suppliers, such as a `part1` that occurs with supplier Bar and Foo, or Bar and Nom, but I have more than 20 suppliers.

Answer (score 0):

Use grouping to compute the number of suppliers per part:

```
SELECT part1
FROM parts
GROUP BY part1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT supplier) >= 2;
```

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks. This one returns parts without repetition.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using `exists`:

```
select p.*
from parts p
where exists (select 1 from parts p2 where p2.part1 = p.part1 and p2.supplier <> p.supplier);
```

If you only wanted the list of parts, then I would recommend `group by` and `having`.  But you want the complete rows, so `exists` better fits your use case.

Comment: In p1.supplier, do you mean p?

Answer (score 0):

I think you also could try this solution using group by and having:

```
SELECT ar.part1, ar.supplier
FROM parts ar
WHERE ar.part1 NOT IN
    (SELECT ar.part1
     FROM parts ar
     GROUP BY ar.part1
     HAVING  count(*) = 1)
GROUP BY ar.part1, ar.supplier 
HAVING  count(*) = 1
ORDER BY ar.part1, ar.supplier;
```